# AWS Gateway not applying mappings on external calls

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a AWS Gateway endpoint: `mypath/{some_id}`.

I have a custome mapping to send that id to my Lambda function, as well as sending Gateway's stage (dev or prod):

```
{
  "some_id": "$input.params('some_id')",
  "aws_gateway_stage": "$context.stage"
}
```

In addition to this, I send some custom data on the request body, lets say `{ "some_attr": "some_value" }`.

I have 2 separated but related problems:

1. If I hit the endpoint from outside (using `curl` for example), the **mapping is not applied** and only `{ "some_attr": "some_value" }` reaches my Lambda function as the `event`.
2. If I hit the endpoint from within Gateway's Dashboard (by using the 'test' option), the mapping is applied but the **request body params are hidden**, so only `{ "some_id": "$input.params('some_id')", "aws_gateway_stage": "$context.stage" }` reaches my Lambda function as the event.

What can be the cause for this behavior?

Comment: 'test' from Gateway dashboard will send the header Content-Type=application/json. Your mapping template will be for a specific content-type. Are you sending the content-type of application/json when testing from curl?

Comment: That was problem. Thanks!